# echo taking too much time

Tags: php, profiler

I want to improve the page generation time for the php script.
But as per php profiler report, it is the echo statement which is taking around 0.9 sec.

I am using "**php-5.3**" in a "CentOS release 5.6 (Final)" machine.

Here goes the php code---

```
<?php
    $AllTimerDataValue = ClMiscellaneous::getAllActivityData();//returns an array of size maximum 40
    $output = '<input type="hidden" name="actions" value="'.$_REQUEST['actions'].'">';
    $output.= '<table id="gradient-style-dup" class="activity_stream_container_tbl" rules="all" align="center">';
    $output.= ClMiscellaneous::getHtmlViewOfSingleActivity($AllTimerDataValue);//returns html code based on $AllTimerDataValue
    $output.= '</table>';
    echo $output; // This is taking around 0.9 sec
?>
```

For profiling I am using "DBG Bar" Add-on of firefox, and in the server-side I am using DBG module of php.

Comment: What is the size (strlen()) of the output?

Comment: Try to run this script with commented out last string - 1 second different will be noticeable.

Comment: I find it extremely hard to believe that a simple echo would take nearly a second.  Can you comment out the echo and run the benchmark again?  Have you tried benchmarking with microtime?

Comment: Do you use any output buffering?

Comment: Also you want to use `htmlspecialchars()` for the output of the `$_REQUEST['actions']`

Comment: Yes, you are right, after commenting the echo page generation time is 0.15 sec. And for your information, the echo is sending about 153KB of html code.

Comment: My bet is its actually the call to ClMiscellaneous::getHtmlViewOfSingleActivity that is slow. I'm curious; you say $AllTimerDataValue is an array - an array of activities, or an array of a single activity's data? If the former, I would guess you don't need to send the entire array to getHtmlViewOfSingleActivity...

Comment: Hi, actually $AllTimerDataValue contains an array of 40 elements each contains 'user-name', 'url' and 'description' and ClMiscellaneous::getHtmlViewOfSingleActivity
generates a DIV for each 40 elements and so I need to send the whole array to that function. So, my final question is is there any buffer related issue for PHP while
executing the echo statement.

Comment: Maybe you're echoing a class which then calls __toString() that takes a while?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the reason is you are using debugger at your server, something that I'm sure about is that echo won't take 0.9 sec.

however you may like to try print() instead of echo();